# Program doesn't show expected output

Tags: c, arrays

The expected output of the following C program is to print the elements in the array. But when actually run, it doesn't do so.

```
  #include<stdio.h>

  #define TOTAL_ELEMENTS (sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]))
  int array[] = {23,34,12,17,204,99,16};

  int main()
  {
      int d;

      for(d=-1;d <= (TOTAL_ELEMENTS-2);d++)
          printf("%d\n",array[d+1]);//printing the array

      return 0;
  }//looks simple but no result
```

What's going wrong? Why am I not getting any output?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the comparison

```
d <= (TOTAL_ELEMENTS-2)
```

`TOTAL_ELEMENTS` has type `size_t` so `d` is converted to unsigned.  For, say, `sizeof(size_t)==4`, this makes the test

```
0xffffffff < 5
```

which fails, causing the loop to exit.

If you really want to start your loop counter from -1

```
d <= (int)(TOTAL_ELEMENTS-2)
```

would work

Comment: Actually `TOTAL_ELEMENTS` has type `size_t`, which is *some* implementation-defined unsigned type, not necessarily `unsigned int`. But the main issue is indeed described correctly.

Comment: Or you could just rewrite this to look semi-normal and use d=0 and not add 1 inside the index operator...

Comment: @UpAndAdam: But then it wouldn't demonstrate the issue. The existence of the deliberately tortured arithmetic means this code was clearly intended as some kind of brain-teaser.

Comment: @UpAndAdam: I don't dispute no effort has been *demonstrated*. But even if it was, there's only one comparison in the entire program, so a debugger won't help narrow that down, and even if you manage to get a debugger to show you the value of `TOTAL_ELEMENTS-2`, it's still going to show you that that's 5, and that `d` is -1. He clearly shows an understanding that -1 is less than 5, and without the knowledge of how signed vs unsigned comparisons can work, the loop really does look like it ought to work "as expected", I don't really see any laziness in this particular case.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths Then he should say "Why does comparison of -1 < 5 " not return the value I expect... but he doesn't. If it's only one line of comparison then reduce the problem to just that and spare us all the irrelevant stuff.

Comment: @UpAndAdam: He could have worded his question more clearly and specifically, for sure. On the other hand, it's a short code segment to begin with, the issue is kind of obvious, and he does comment it "looks simple but no result", so I'm not sure is necessary. Either way, no big deal, just seems like an OK question to me, other than the fact that the same question (literally the same, same values of the array elements, and everything) has been asked here a bunch of times before, but everyone calls it "program doesn't show expected output" and similar which makes it hard to find.

Comment: Which is exactly why it should be truncated to the actual question at hand... thanks for proving my point for me.